# Android update UI main thread issue

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I am having trouble figuring out how this is done in android. It is a very simple application, a TextView taking up the majority of the screen and a ToggleButton on the bottom. When the button is toggled on the phone communicates over a socket every 5 seconds requesting new data, this new data must then be prepended to the top of the TextView.

Because you don't want to do the 5 second timers or the network activity in the main thread I've been using asynctask but threads outside the main thread can't update the TextView.

Here is some pseudocode for what I am doing. How can I make it so updateView is called each time new data is received, but from the main thread?

```
Communication(IO) Variables
```

LinkedList of strings for TextView

```
public class MyActivity {
//setContentView
//setup network connection
//getTextView 
//getToggleButton
    //when clicked on start asynctask GetData
    //when clicked off stop GetData (set global boolean to false)
}

public void updateView(){

//take linked list and make one String of proper size for textview
//setTextView

}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask {

//while we want to get data (global boolean variable)
    //send request
    //wait for response
    //*update global text variable for the view* 
    //sleep for 5 seconds

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside your `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute()` or in `onProgressUpdate()`method. From there you can trigger updates on the UI. I assume that in `doInBackground()` you fetch the data.

Answer (score 3):

AsyncTask has a function called OnProgressUpdate.  If you ovverride it, and add code here, it will be executed on the UI thread

To call the OnProgressUpdate function, you call PublishProgress.

Comment: thanks that did it, if I could select multiple correct answers I would. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)
```

and `publishProgress(Value...)` each time new data is received.

The `doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask does not run on the UI Thread and that is why it can't update the UI.

Another method would be using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: thanks that did it, if I could select multiple correct answers I would. Appreciate the help.