# Android Socket error with no message

Tags: java, android, sockets

I create a simple network-testing application.
But It doesn't work and always throw error at `Socket()`.
I tried to check error message by using `getMessage()`, there was no message printed.
What should I do?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(14100);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] arr = new byte[100];
        in.read(arr);
        System.out.println(new String(arr));
        String str = "Hello Client";
        out.write(str.getBytes());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try{
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ignored){}
        try{
            serverSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ignored){}
    }
}
```

Below is android code for Client.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_tv);

    Socket socket = null;
    try{
        socket = new Socket("192.168.0.52",14100);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        String str = "Hello Server";
        out.write(str.getBytes());
        byte arr[] = new byte[100];
        in.read(arr);
        tv.setText(new String(arr));
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    finally{
        try{
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ignored){
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I added permisson for android in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: at what line you got error?

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` try using `e.printStackTrace();` to get more information about the exception

Comment: you can't do it on the ui thread, use AsyncTask or something

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android update UI main thread issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818790/android-update-ui-main-thread-issue)

Comment: Do you really catch all Exceptions and ignore them? If not, please add exception handling code. If you do, add an "e.printStackTrace()" to each catch and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Move the socket code out of UI main thread `onCreate()` to an `AsyncTask` or a regular thread.

For a quick test, wrap all your socket code into a thread like so:

```
    new Thread() { 
        public void run() {
            // Move your socket code here for a quick test
        }
    }.start();
```